# Web Forms based web application URLs without the ".aspx" like stackoverflow.com

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'd like to know if it is possible to have the URLs of the pages of a Webforms application  display without the `.aspx` extension.

For instace, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` instead of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.aspx`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The technology that stackoverflow uses has been discussed many many times, what you are looking for is the ASP.Net MVC Framework

http://www.asp.net/mvc

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc

This can also be done using URL rewriters

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by using either **[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)** or the [routing engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.01.extremeaspnet.aspx) by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You want Asp.Net Routing.  Best place to start is here:
http://haacked.com/Tags/Routing/default.aspx

If you are using IIS7 it is easy.  IIS6 requires a little more work.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally done using a routing engine in a framework. However if you want to do this for an arbitrary application it's really done using Apache's Mod_Rewrite.