# How to make a URL not end with web page extension?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web Forms based web application URLs without the “.aspx” linke stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787961/web-forms-based-web-application-urls-without-the-aspx-linke-stackoverflow-com)

For instance if you create a question on stack overflow, the URL is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Does this URL actually map to a webpage? how does it not have and extension such as ask.aspx?

How do I accomplish the same thing?